# Why are auto variables deduced to pointers when initialized by string literals?

Tags: c++, c++11, type-inference, auto, string-literals

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

int main()
{
    const char a[] = "hello world";
    const char * p = "hello world";
    auto x = "hello world";

    if (typeid(x) == typeid(a))
        std::cout << "It's an array!\n";

    else if (typeid(x) == typeid(p))
        std::cout << "It's a pointer!\n";   // this is printed

    else
        std::cout << "It's Superman!\n";
}
```

Why is `x` deduced to be a pointer when string literals are actually arrays?

> A narrow string literal has type "array of *n* `const char`" [2.14.5 String Literals [lex.string] §8]

Comment: My reading of the standard, for `auto` and declared type seem to indicate it should be an array, as you expect. They clearly say it resolves like a template parameter as well, which certainly would be an array (though I just tested it an in GCC the template form of the above also reports "pointer").

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The feature `auto` is based on template argument deduction and template argument deduction behaves the same, specifically according to §14.8.2.1/2 (C++11 standard):

- If P is not a reference type

  - If A is an array type, the pointer type produced by the array-to-pointer conversion is used in place of A for type deduction

If you want the type of the expression `x` to be an array type, just add `&` after `auto`:

```
auto& x = "Hello world!";
```

Then, the `auto` placeholder will be deduced to be `const char[13]`. This is also similar to function templates taking a reference as parameter. Just to avoid any confusion: The declared type of x will be *reference*-to-array.

Comment: Note that that means `x` here isn't an array, it's a reference to an array. The subtle difference is that after `auto& x = "a"; auto& y = "a";`, `&x == &y` *may* return true, depending on whether the two distinct string literals are merged.

Comment: @hvd: Right, that's why I specifically said "type of the expression x" instead of "declared type of x". But it's surely worth mentioning. Thanks. :)

Comment: `auto&& x = "Hello world!";` is also a possibility (and yields an lvalue reference to an array, just like `auto&` does in this instance).

Comment: @LucDanton Right, I always forget that string literals are lvalues.

Answer (score 6):

> Why is x deduced to be a pointer when string literals are actually arrays?

Because of array-to-pointer conversion.

If `x` is to be deduced as array, only if the following is allowed:

```
const char m[]          = "ABC";

const char n[sizeof(m)] = m; //error
```

In C++, an arrray cannot be initialized with another array (like above). In such cases, the source array decays into pointer type, and you're allowed to do this instead:

```
const char* n = m; //ok
```

The rules for type-inference with `auto` is same as the rules of type-deduction in function template:

```
template<typename T>
void f(T n);

f(m);     //T is deduced as const char*
f("ABC"); //T is deduced as const char*

auto n = m;     //n's type is inferred as const char*
auto n = "ABC"; //n's type is inferred as const char*
```

§7.1.6.4/6  says about `auto` specifier:

> The type deduced for the variable d is then the deduced A determined using the rules of template argument deduction from a function call (14.8.2.1) ...

Comment: `x` isn't initialised with `a`. `x` is initialised with `"hello world"`, which is a valid initialiser for an array of char.

Comment: Sure it does. Your answer only explains why `auto x = a;` would make `x` a pointer, but that is not what's in the question.

Comment: Except for one difference: they're valid initialisers for arrays of char. You have `const char m[] = "ABC";` in your own answer, just as you are saying that arrays aren't valid initialisers for other arrays!

Comment: Your edited version appears to agree with GCC even if you add reference qualifiers: `template <typename T> void f(T&&); f("abc");` T is deduced as array. Same for `auto&& x = "abc";`

Comment: @hvd: Added quote from the spec.

Answer (score -2):

If you want x to be deduced as array, you can use

```
decltype(auto) x = "hello world";
```

Comment: `x` gets deduced as a reference to an array here.