# How to initialize static members without repeating their type

Tags: c++, c++11

Let's say we have the following class:

```
class A {
    static SomeLongType b;
};
```

Now we have to initialize it in the appropriate cpp file. I can think of the following ways:

```
SomeLongType A::b{}; // repetition of SomeLongType
decltype(A::b) A::b{}; // A::b written two times
```

Both seem to be kind of cumbersome to me. Is there a better way?

Comment: Just carping: You miss `public::` in the class `A`. :)

Comment: If the type is of an integer or enumeration type, it can be initialized in the class declaration (in C++11).  Otherwise, no, you have to initialize it in the implementation (much like member functions that are not implemented in the class declaration).

Comment: Try to use template class with static variable type as parameter.

Comment: It'd be nice to use `auto`, but see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14285198/why-doesnt-the-c11-auto-keyword-work-for-static-members?rq=1

Comment: @herohuyongtao Nope, b can be private. But `static` variables need an definition.

Comment: Since you are using `decltype` can we assume C++11?  I've edited the tags.

Answer (score 3):

The perfect solution would be to use C++11 `auto`. But as ecatmur commented, thats not allowed by the language.

Why not just define a simple macro?

```
#define DEFINE(x) decltype(x) x{}

struct A
{
    static SomeLongType b;
};

DEFINE( A::b );
```

I really hate C macros, but they are usefull in certain cases.

Comment: And for bonus points, you can make it a [variadic macro](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html) to take care of more complicated constructors.  Not sure how portable that syntax is, though...

Comment: @XavierHolt: Variadic macros are allowed in c++11.

Comment: @XavierHolt or just define the macro as `#define DEFINE(x) decltype(x) x`, using it as `DEFINE(A::b);`, or `DEFINE(A::b){ some params here };`, or `DEFINE(A::b) = something;`. I think its more clear than `#define DEFINE(X , params...)`   `DEFINE(A::b , p1 , p2 , p3, etc )`, and its less tricky and more flexible.