# Defining static constexpr auto class variable

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, c++14, auto

The following code fails to link due to an undefined reference:

```
// file.h
struct S {
    static constexpr auto x = 0;
};

// file.cpp
int main() {
    auto const & ref = S::x;
}
```

Following the advice of [Why doesn't the C++11 'auto' keyword work for static members?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14285198/why-doesnt-the-c11-auto-keyword-work-for-static-members), this seems to work with clang 3.5:

```
// file.h
struct S {
    static constexpr auto x = 0;
};

// file.cpp
constexpr decltype(S::x) S::x;

int main() {
    auto const & ref = S::x;
}
```

Is it actually valid C++? This seems to violate the rule of "auto everywhere or nowhere" that functions follow (you can forward declare a function that returns auto and then define it to return auto, but you cannot mix auto with non-auto).

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is, `x`'s type is `int` as soon as its declaration is complete.

Comment: My concern in this code is that at least in C++11, it might deduce a type of std::initializer_list<int> rather than int?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `auto` *type-specifier* serves two related but separate purposes

[dcl.spec.auto] / 1

> The `auto` and `decltype(auto)` *type-specifier*s are used to
>   designate a placeholder type that will be replaced later by deduction
>   from an initializer. The `auto` *type-specifier* is also used to
>   introduce a function type having a *trailing-return-type* or to
>   signify that a lambda is a generic lambda.

In the case of your static member, the type is determined by the initializer, so `x` already has type `int` at the end of its declaration.

[dcl.spec.auto] / 4

> The type of a variable declared using `auto` or `decltype(auto)` is
>   deduced from its initializer.

The rule you mention applies to functions and function templates only, and is unrelated to the use of `auto` when declaring variables.

[dcl.spec.auto] / 13

> Redeclarations or specializations of a function or function template
>   with a declared return type that uses a placeholder type shall also
>   use that placeholder, not a deduced type.