# Why does auto in `auto s = "abc"` yield char pointer instead of char array?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, c++11, types

This program

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    auto s = "Hello, world!\n";
    decltype("Hello, world!\n") t = "Hello, world!\n";
    std::cout << sizeof s << ", ";
    std::cout << sizeof t << ", ";
    std::cout << sizeof "Hello, world!\n" << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

prints

```
4, 15, 15
```

This suggests that the type of `s` is `char *`. This feels wierd considering that the type of the string literal and `t` is `char [15]`.

Why doesn't this program print `15, 15, 15` instead?

Why does `auto` declare a pointer type instead of an array type when assigned to a string literal?

Comment: Array name decay innit... FYI it'll be `const char*`, not `char*`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12016757/auto-with-string-literals

Comment: @Galik  it only decays in some of those cases . There is no decay in `char const (&s)[6] = "Hello";` .

Comment: no, but you haven't explained how `auto s  = "Hello";` differs from that case

Comment: @M.M Yeah, I'm getting myself tangled up in terminology.